# Sass calc decleration dropped Chrome

Tags: sass, css-calc

I am writing a simple grid layout using Sass. I am trying to use `calc()` to determine the width in relative units `%`. To test the styles, I am using a simple HTML file.

Problem: Inspecting the results with dev tools on Chrome, it shows that the width declaration with the `calc()` call is dropped as `Invalid property value`. Here is the code:

src.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="X-UA Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./../css/12grid_rwd.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <main class="grid_1" role="main">
            <!--<header class="grid_12" role="banner">Header</header>
            <nav class="grid_3" role="navigation">Nav</nav>
            <section class="grid_9">Content</section>
            <footer class="grid_12" role="contentinfo">Footer</footer> -->
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

src.scss

```
$context-width: 1200;
// Grid >> 12 Columns
.grid {
    &_1 { width: calc(calc(80/#{$context-width})*100); }
}
```

generated css:

```
.grid_1 {
  width: calc(calc(80/1200)*100); }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) call's can't be nested, it expects expression to calculate, it is the reason why your property is dropped by browser.

Moreover since your expression contains plain math - it can be calculated by Sass itself. Moreover from your expression it looks like you want resulted value to be percent from container's width, in this case you can use [`percentage()`](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#percentage-instance_method) function from Sass:

```
$context-width: 1200;
$column-width: 80;
// Grid >> 12 Columns
.grid {
  @for $n from 1 through 12 {
    &_#{$n} { 
      width: percentage($column-width * $n/$context-width); 
    }
  }
}
```

You can play with this example at [Sassmeister](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/3f88d1040e2e885cfcf7a4f377e11d2e).

Comment: Thanks so much. It made the code so much simple. I am adding the complete snippet as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Following the suggestions from @Flying, I was able to implement the logic I wanted. The code is much simpler to understand and debug.

Goal: To have a 1280 pixels grid system with 20px margin on container and 20px padding on the grids. Note that these margin and padding properties are for left and right only (10px each side). Starting with a first grid, class `grid_1`, at 80px, `grid_2` will be `80*2 + 20*(2-1)` where `80 is the fixed column width, 2 is the grid number, 20 is the padding`and so on. The scss code is as follows:

src.scss

```
$context-width: 1200;
$column-width: 80;
$fixed-gutter: 20;

// Grid >> 12 Columns

@mixin width-calc($n) {
  @if $n == 1{
    width: percentage(($column-width * $n)/$context-width);
  }
  @else {
    $c: $column-width * $n + ($fixed-gutter * ($n - 1));
    width: percentage(($c)/$context-width);
  }
}

.grid {
  @for $n from 1 through 12 {
    &_#{$n} {
      @include width-calc($n);
    }
  }
}
```

The generated css:

```
.grid_1 {
  width: 6.66667%;
}
.grid_2 {
  width: 15%;
}
.grid_3 {
  width: 23.33333%;
}
.grid_4 {
  width: 31.66667%;
}
.grid_5 {
  width: 40%;
}
.grid_6 {
  width: 48.33333%;
}
.grid_7 {
  width: 56.66667%;
}
.grid_8 {
  width: 65%;
}
.grid_9 {
  width: 73.33333%;
}
.grid_10 {
  width: 81.66667%;
}
.grid_11 {
  width: 90%;
}
.grid_12 {
  width: 98.33333%;
}
```